# Wordpress - custom taxonomy template - page not found?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post and a custom taxonomy for that post and both the post type and the taxonomy work fine:

```
function venue_post() {
   $rewrite = array(
   'slug'                => 'venue',
   'with_front'          => true,
   'pages'               => true,
   'feeds'               => true,
   );

   $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Venue', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Venue Posts', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'locationCategories' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-groups',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,        
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
      'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'venue_post', $args );
}

function venue_locationCategories() {
  $rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'venue-location',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
   );
 }
   register_taxonomy( 'locationCategories', array( 'venue_post' ), $args );
```

I have then setup a template page named the following:

```
taxonomy-locationCategories.php
```

but when I visit the taxonomy page e.g. `www.example.com/locationcategories/london` 
I just get a 404. Any idea what I'm missing I have refreshed permalinks.

Comment: You added a custom slug there "venue-location", so probably your url should be www.example.com/venue-location/london

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using rewrite rule which allows you to change taxonomy slug from taxonomy name.

Your taxonomy is locationCategories and your taxonomy slug is venue-loaction.

**Archive page**

```
www.example.com/venue-loaction/
```

**Custom Post Type page**

```
www.example.com/venue-loaction/london
```

Comment: Brilliant @Tautvydas Banys, can't believe I missed that! Will mark as solved when I can!